# Insert word at beginning of line using sed and line number

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to insert a word at the beginning of a line specified with line number, using sed. This oneliner works:

```
line="this is my line"; newfile=`sed "6s/.*/word $line/" /opt/file.txt`
```

But my issue is that when i run the code in a script it throws an error:

```
line="this is my line"
newfile=`sed "6s/.*/word $line/" $FILE_PATH`
sed: -e expression #1, char 91: unknown option to `s'
```

Sed version: GNU sed version 4.1.5

Comment: In script also it is working

Comment: Are you sure you are just doing exactly what you said (ie: the value of `$line` does not contain special characters)? It should work. Note if you want to prepend the line and not replace it, it should be: `sed "6s/^/word $line/"`

Comment: You should double quote your FILE_PATH var : `"$FILE_PATH"`.

Comment: @bufh You are right, I edited `$line` for readability, and it does actually contain a bracket [, which is char 91. Can I escape the bracket from the command without editing the `$line` ?

Comment: @bufh I used your prepend syntax instead and it works perfectly, thank you! =)

Comment: I would redirect you to the solutions proposed on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern; you would do something like: `line=$(echo "$line|sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g')` before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have some symbols in $line and sed can't work with them without escaping it. Char 91 is "["

Try this:

```
line='this is my line'
newfile=`sed "6s/.*/word $line/" $FILE_PATH`
```

or this

```
line="this is my line"
newfile=`sed '6s/.*/word '$line'/' $FILE_PATH`
```

maybe it will help

Comment: https://github.com/legionus/libshell.git has handy quote_sed_regexp_variable() and quote_sed_regexp(), just in case